# Catalyst 2960-X no xmodem or tftp transfer

Tags: cisco, tftp, cisco-catalyst

I tried to upgrade the IOS on a Catalyst 2960-X stack with three members. The upgrade failed and left me with three switches without bootable files. So I connect to the rommon via console using TeraTerm and set the baud rate to 115200. I type copy xmodem: flash:/c2960x-universal.bin and start the xmodem transfer - and nothing happens. What could be the cause?
[XModem does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIbaJ.jpg)

Puzzled, I try to upload via tftp. I connect the management interface to a switch running a dhcp server, set the variables in the switch, make sure my PC can be reached via ping, and start the download. The tftp server log shows that the file was requested, but that no data was sent. The switch says "successfully copied", but the file has zero bytes. What is wrong here?
[TFTP does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZclZ.jpg)

Could the failed upgrade have corrupted the flash memory?
Any feedback is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the bin file on the PC that was corrupted. I extracted it again from the tar archive and now it's uploading. Sigh. Always return to zero when you're stuck.

Comment: Glad you've resolved your issue. The file hashes Cisco provides can be useful to avoid issues like these. Please be sure to [mark your answer accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.